# the smallest boost when searching by synonyms in elasticSearch in nest c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

There is a dictionary with synonyms, I add it when creating an index:

```
private string[] synonyms = new string[]{
                                        "city,town",
                                        "Blvd., boulevard",
                                        "Ave., avenue"
                                        };
```

Creating the index itself:

```
 public async Task CreateAddressHousesIndexAsync()
        {
            var existIndex = (await _elasticClient.Indices.ExistsAsync(_elasticSettings.AddressIndexHousesLevel)).Exists;
            if (existIndex)
                return;

            await _elasticClient.Indices.CreateAsync(_elasticSettings.AddressIndexHousesLevel, c =>
                c.Map<ElasticAddressHouseLevel>(d => d.AutoMap()
                        .Properties(w => w
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Id)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.DistrictName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Country)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.RegionName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.DistrictName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.LocalityName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.StreetName)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.HouseNumber)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.BuildNumber)
                                .Analyzer("custom_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Keyword(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.PostalCode)
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Latitude)
                            )
                            .Text(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.Longitude)
                            )
                            .Date(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.ChangedAt)
                            )
                            .Date(e => e
                                .Name(r => r.CreatedAt)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Settings(s => s
                        .Analysis(z => z
                            .TokenFilters(tf =>
                                tf.Synonym("address_synonym",
                                    syn =>
                                        syn.Synonyms(synonyms) // my synonyms
                                )
                            )
                            .CharFilters(cf => cf
                                .Mapping("custom_mapping", p => p
                                    .Mappings(new[]
                                    {
                                    "ё => е",
                                    "Ё => Е"
                                    })
                                )
                                .PatternReplace("replace_dot", w => w
                                    .Pattern(@"\.")
                                    .Replacement(" "))
                            )
                            .Analyzers(q => q
                                .Custom("custom_analyzer", w => w
                                    .CharFilters("custom_mapping", "replace_dot")
                                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                                    .Filters("lowercase", "address_synonym")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            );
        }
```

When searching in the index, using the example of the query "Zhukov Avenue", it gives out a selection of other avenues, and the desired address "Marshal Zhukov Avenue" turns out to be at the bottom, how to make synonyms have the lowest priority and I got my address first, or better how to specify synonyms in the filters when querying also with the least boost, without adding them when creating the index?